# Include Gmail signature when preparing message from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, email

I need to open and prepopulate (compose) a Gmail message. The following code does indeed compose the message however the users default signature is omitted that is undesirable.

How can I 'compose a message, prepopulate the message (I've got this part down) however ALSO include the default signature?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=" & Company_Main_Contact_email_1TextBox.Text & "&su=SUBJECT&body= Please enter your message here")
```

Comment: Use GoogleMailAPI for such things... More here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to the limitations of how Gmail builds the emails, when you supply the "Body" parameter it assumes that you have defined the message.  You will need to omit this portion and have the user add their message.